# can we make instance of abstract class in java

Tags: java

Sorry for asking, The Fact we know that
in java you cannot create an instance of an abstract class because it does not have a complete implementation. The purpose of an abstract class is to function as a base for subclasses.
Then about NumberFormat class in java is abstract right ??

the question is how about this code :

```
NumberFormat numberFormatter = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
```

1. what does this mean ? if im not wrong, this mean that we make an object instance of NumberFormat using numberFormatter ? or what ?
2. NumberFormater is abstract right ? so we need to make subclass of it.
3. if no.1 question i ask is false fact, then why we use `numberFormatter.format(x);` on this code line
   `String numberStr = numberFormatter.format(x);`

the full code is shown bellow, Thankyou very much for your response.

```
public class NumberFormatToy {   
    public static void main(String args[]) {      
        double x = 1000.0/3.0;      
        NumberFormat numberFormatter = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();      
        NumberFormat currFormatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();      
        NumberFormat percentFormatter = NumberFormat.getPercentInstance();      

        String numberStr = numberFormatter.format(x);      
        String currStr = currFormatter.format(x);       
        String percentStr = percentFormatter.format(x);      

        System.out.println("double 1000.0/3.0 berformat number   : "+ numberStr);      
        System.out.println("double 1000.0/3.0 berformat currency : "+ currStr);      
        System.out.println("double 1000.0/3.0 berformat percent  : "+ percentStr);   
    }
}
```

Comment: `NumberFormat.getNumberInstance()` is a static factory method. It gives you something that is an instance of a subclass of `NumberFormat`, but hides *which* subclass.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you already understand, since `NumberFormat` is abstract it is not possible to do this:

```
new NumberFormat();
```

However, the actual object that is created can (and often does) differ from the type of the variable that references that object. In one of your examples - `NumberFormat numberFormatter = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();` – the object that is returned by `NumberFormat.getNumberInstance()` is something which extends `NumberFormat`.

This line of code prints out the class of the object returned by `NumberFormat.getNumberInstance()`:

```
System.out.println(NumberFormat.getNumberInstance().getClass());
```

which prints out:

```
class java.text.DecimalFormat
```

If you look up the [Javadoc for DecimalFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html), you'll see that it extends `NumberFormat`.

You could also call `NumberFormat.getNumberInstance()` and store the result using one of the *interfaces* that `NumberFormat` implements (you can see those [in the Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html)). Here's an example showing how to create a variable of type `Serializable`:

```
Serializable s = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
```

and similarly, it is not valid to create an instance of `Serializable` using a constructor, so this isn't allowed: `new Serializable()`.

Answer (score 1):

The `NumberFormat` class is indeed abstract but static methods cannot be abstract.

So, you can define a static method in your abstract class that returns objects of classes that inherit from your abstract class.

The methods `getNumberInstance`, `getCurrencyInstance`, `getPercentInstance`, etc are all static methods that return an object of some class that extends `NumberFormat`.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a code like that - Collection list = Collections.asList("a", "b"); that means that you get object of interface Collection? Of cause no. This only means that static method asList() returns something that implements Collection. 
  So, if you will see a code like that, be sure that a method return object of some class and if you want to know which one then just CTRL + click on this method and your IDE show you code of this one and you will see what it return.